# How to access the 2nd checkbox that have the same class name and tag?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to access a 2nd or 3rd Checkbox Element that have the same class name and tag..Each of the checkbox is enclosed in a separate div and the div also has the same class name. 
I previously searched on stackoverflow and Google and tried some of the following but none of them is working

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div)[@class='classname value'])[2]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='classname value']) [position()=2]")
```

Also

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span)[@class='classname value'])[2]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='classname value']) [position()=2]")
```

This is somehow the elements look like by inspection

```
<div class='a checkbox'>
 <label><input type='checkbox'><span class='b'>Paid</span></label>
</div>
<div class='a checkbox'>
 <label><input type='checkbox'><span class='b'>Free</span></label>
</div>
```

I basically want to access the checkbox with Free Text..My Overall Code is this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=python&p=1")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='All Filters']"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-body']//label[.//span[@data-purpose='filter-option-title' and text()='Free']]/input[@type='checkbox']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your code to be looking like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=python&p=1")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//span[text()='All Filters']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[@title and .//span/span[text()='Free']]"))).click()
```

Comment: Hey this is not working as i mentioned in my question as well

Comment: Have you checked my test? How is it different from your real case? I took your example.

Comment: Yeah i checked....Basically i am trying to access the Free checkbox from this page
https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=python&p=1
click All Filter> Free Checkbox

Comment: As you can see from the tool I tested the solution in, the xPath actually locates the check-box that you require. If it is not working for you, the issue might be not in just xpath.

Comment: I tried it but this it throws an error of 'No Such Element'. So when i click on the All Filter Option on DOM, it opens a big menu...From there i need to select that Free text so is that menu then the part of DOM once clicked right?

Comment: Right. Since there is JavaScript addressing UI changes, the pane might open too fast. Try to wait for the element.

Comment: I waited for a long time even included this statement time.sleep(30) but still it is unable to check the checkbox

Comment: can you update your question with the code that you have by the moment?

Comment: Check my second update. The issue might be that you're locating `span` but not a `button`. The xpath that you use to locate check-box then does not work for me at all even when the pane is open and I'm testing manually in dev tools.

Comment: Thank You...Can you please provide the complete code that you have used while locating that checkbox?

Comment: OK...Have you tried it on the browser..Cause i checked it now and this time it 
      throws the following error
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input type="checkbox"> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: This is beacuse your screen resolution is not big enough and your checkbox is out of view port. Try the solution with scroll. I have updated the code.

Comment: It now says that ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input type="checkbox"> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: Yes...Finally it worked...Thank You So Much for your Hugh Help
Can you now please one last time explain, how you located these element...That Xpath part specially?

Comment: It is alsways a matter of trials. Picking the proper xpath for UI is not the same as for just an XML document since even if you can locate the element in DOM, that element might not receive your interaction attempt because of CSS issues or JS issues. I always start from the very specific xpath that I would use in pure XML. Then if it does not work I try the elements one or two levels up and one or two levels down the tree,

Comment: That is Awesome bro..
Thank You so much

Comment: Just mark as correct. It is reputation-independent action.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `contain` If the **DOM** only contain only one **Free** text as shown below example.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Free')]")
```

If the **DOM** contain multiple **Free** text, then you need to pass it to **List** and based on the text position you need to iterate the **List**.

Comment: @JoeAnn Check how many free text in your DOM, if you have more than one pass it to list and access based on the text position. Above example only find the elements it will not do any action, you need to call the action (Click)

Comment: I only have one Free text in my DOM
Basically i am trying to access the Free checkbox from this page udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=python&p=1 click All Filter> Free Checkbox

Comment: i have updated the question by including the whole code that i have at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath to click on Free checkbox on udemy account.

```
 //div[@class='modal-body']//label[.//span[@data-purpose='filter-option-title' and text()='Free']]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` And Following XPATH locator.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-body']//label[.//span[@data-purpose='filter-option-title' and text()='Free']]/input[@type='checkbox']"))).click()
```

---

Here is the code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("path of the chrome driver")
driver.get("http://udemy.com/courses/search/?src=ukw&q=python&p=1")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='All Filters']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='modal-body']//label[.//span[@data-purpose='filter-option-title' and text()='Free']]/input[@type='checkbox']"))).click()
```

Comment: I tried it but this it throws an error of 'No Such Element'. So when i click on the All Filter Option on DOM, it opens a big menu...From there i need to select that Free text so is that menu then the part of DOM once clicked right?

Comment: @JoeAnn : I have updated the complete code.try and let me know.If you get error then post the entire error.

Comment: Yes i got an error once again but this time it throws this error...Here it is
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @JoeAnn : where are you  getting error to click on `checkbox` or `All filters`?

Comment: The 'All filter' is clicked successfully but the checkbox can't be located

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `<input>` element presumably moving ahead you need to invoke `click()` on the element with respect to the text **Free**, you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH 1*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='a checkbox']//label//span[@class='b' and text()='Free']//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH 2*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b' and text()='Free']//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried it but this it throws an error of 'No Such Element'. So when i click on the All Filter Option on DOM, it opens a big menu...From there i need to select that Free text so is that menu then the part of DOM once clicked right?

Comment: @JoeAnn I don't have visibility of the `All Filter Option` element. So once the menu opens use the line of code to click on the element with text as `Free`.

Comment: i have updated the question by including the whole code that i have at the moment